# Right side of Fractal Tree Missing using turtle in python 3

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, fractals

I tried to make a fractal tree in python using the turtle module. This is what I have so far:

```
    import turtle
    t1 = turtle.Turtle()
    t1.speed(0)
    t1.left(90)
    t1.hideturtle()
    def branch(len):
      t1.forward(len)
      if(len>20):
        angle = 45
        xCor = t1.xcor()
        yCor = t1.ycor()
        t1.left(angle)
        branch(len*0.67)
        t1.goto(xCor, yCor)
        xCor = t1.xcor()
        yCor = t1.ycor()
        t1.left(-angle)
        branch(len*0.67)
        t1.goto(xCor, yCor)
    branch(100)
```

However, this results in the right part of the fractal tree missing, and same with half of the left part of the tree.

Here is a picture:
[Result of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gobhR.png)

Here is the other picture where I multiplied the angle by 0.1

[image: Result of Code]

Here are the changes i made to my code:

[image: Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the tree you want you need to save the turtle's heading before you do a branch so that you can restore it after you do a branch. The easy way to do that is to use the `.heading` and `.setheading` methods.

I've also made another minor change. I use the `.position` method to get the turtle's current position in a tuple, rather than making two separate calls.

BTW, it's not a good idea to use `len` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `len` function.

```
import turtle

t1 = turtle.Turtle()

t1.speed(0)
t1.left(90)
t1.hideturtle()
# Move the turtle down the screen to make room for the tree
t1.up()
t1.forward(-200)
t1.down()

angle = 45

def branch(length):
    t1.forward(length)
    if length > 20:
        xy = t1.position()
        head = t1.heading()
        length *= 0.67

        t1.left(angle)
        branch(length)

        t1.setheading(head)
        t1.goto(xy)
        t1.right(angle)
        branch(length)

        t1.goto(xy)

branch(100)
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to rotate the turtle to the right by `2 * angle` when you are done with the left branch. Rotating it by `angle` will only bring it back to the original direction.

Comment: it actually works now, but i had to mess around with the values, instead of multiplying it by 2, i did it by 0.1 and it works just fine